# Windows 7 share internet connection with multiple network interfaces

Tags: windows-7, ics

On Windows 7 an existing internet connection can be shared with one other network interface through the default system control center.
In my case, however, I need to share the connection with more than one interface. Is it possible without installing any additional software?

To setup ICS for a single interface I have used the following option: `Properties of Adapter -> Details -> Sharing -> Allow other users...`

Comment: What is the system control center that you are refereeing to? Do you mean this third party software here: http://www.kls-soft.com/wscc/

Comment: Also may I ask why you are trying to share the connection with more than one interface(s)?

Comment: I am refering to the default control center of windows. The option I used to share with one interface is included in my updated post. Unfortunatly I cannot post a screenshot yet...

Comment: It would be convenient to use a Windows 7 computer as WLAN repeater and share the connection to a wired network at the same time. This is why I want to share with more than interface.

Comment: Just to be clear. What OS are you trying this on? What service pack is it?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 SP 1

Answer (score 7):

It is really easy but I wasted 3 hours to find how to do this:

1. Disable internet connection sharing if you have enabled it before
2. Select both LAN adapters TO WHICH YOU WANT SHARE INTERNET(by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and clicking on LAN cards)
3. Right click on one of selected and chose from dropdown menu "create bridge connection (or similar)"
4. From now all LAN settings of these LAN cards you should enter in now created bridge connection
5. Now use the standard internet connection sharing to this brige from the LAN adapter which connects to network.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, I had to directly assign the bridge connection an address in the 192.168.137.0/24 network (subnet mask 255.255.255.0). Until I did this, none of the member NICs/virtual switches were able to receive or pass DHCP data or route to the main internet connection.

1. Select the NICs that need to share access to the internet connected NIC (not including the internet connected network interface) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + primary click.
2. Right-click after the group is selected and either create a new bridge, or add them to an existing bridge.
3. Assign a static IP address to the Bridge (I only know the IPv4 range for Windows ICS). I used 192.168.137.2 (just in case .1 is used internally. It probably isn't).
4. If any network connections aren't passing at this point, disconnect and reconnect them, or disable and re-enable them.
5. Turn on Internet Connection Sharing from the Sharing tab of your Internet-connected interface's properties applet, and share it with the bridge

   *Source:* I'm a 10+ year veteran of networking who just had to set up a small private network at work for my personal Hyper-v server on a Windows 10 laptop that I can connect to from my workstation and access my VM server applications and also has access to the internet, but isn't connected to the corporate network and won't ever attempt to act as a default gateway for my internal or internet traffic, but without proper routing equipment (just an unmanaged switch and a mobile hotspot). This works, and I'm still shocked.

***Something I forgot to mention!***
Another fun oddity is the fact that the address of the bridge becomes the default gateway for anything that has to communicate with the bridge. It makes sense based on the name, but I thought it would act more like a switch, given the fact that it has to use the ICS IP address range. (192.168.137.x)

Comment: For step #1, if you only want to share your Internet to one adapter, create a bridge with any 2 adapters and then remove the one you don't want to participate.

Answer (score 0):

The interfaces that you are wanting to use, should have came with software and drivers. If the drivers are installed then you should be able to share the connection with more than one interface via the control panel.

If you are wanting to make one machine a hot spot for all other machines you can setup and AD Hoc network on the host machine. Here is a [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/set-up-a-computer-to-computer-ad-hoc-network) to do so. Please let me know if this helps or not.

Another good reference to share your network [here](http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot)

You can share a network connection like you described in your question so should see a check box like this one:

[image: Network Sharing]

If you don't see that check box, "Allow other network users...", then you need to update your driver

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All my drivers are installed properly, but this option doesn't appear in my control center. What has the device driver to do with such simple networking like connection sharing?

Comment: If you don't have the drivers for your device(s) then they will not work. (Not saying you don't, just wanted you to check) I am going to edit my answer

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the ADhoc network, but Win 7 comes with the functionality to create a real access point: http://kiekeboe100.hoefman.be/blog/2011/03/creating-an-access-point-in-windows-7/. This works just fine for me. 
My actual problem is now how to select **multiple** home networks, because the combobox for `Home networking connection` allows me to select only **one** connection.