# Can a wireless router/AP be connected to a PC to connect WiFi devices inside a Faraday cage when the PC is connected wirelessly outside the cage?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I'm considering buying a wireless router/AP.
However, it must suit my needs, about which I have a question.
In my spare time I stay in a caravan which cannot receive any wireless signals from some public Internet hotspot, because there is none nearby, but I can receive private hotspots from people's homes - this is allowed by the ISP as long as I also allow my own fixed Internet connection at home to be used in this way by everyone nearby.
Now, the signals are rather weak, and I cannot receive them from inside the caravan as it is made from metal which means that I'm inside a Faraday cage.
To overcome this reception problem I placed a big parabolic grid antenna outside on the roof and directed it carefully towards the strongest hotspot, leading the signal inside to a good-quality WiFi-adapter attached to my laptop via USB.
This works great.
Now, can I connect a wireless router/AP (LAN port ? WAN port ?) to my laptop's unused Ethernet port so as to enable wireless Internet inside the caravan as well to use it with my wireless-only tablet and smartphones ?
What network mode do I have to choose to make it work if this is at all possible ?

Comment: What you need to do is to create a hotspot on your laptop and connect any other device to it. It's a trivial task but methodology will differ depending on your OS.

Comment: I want a hardware solution - wireless router/AP if this works - not a software solution that is OS specific, as the laptop runs different OS's.

Comment: If the adapter is connected via USB then you're stuck with a software based solution anyway. A hardware based solution would require an AP inside your caravan which is connected to the antenna outside. Then you can start a wireless hotspot from that AP eliminating the need for a laptop

Comment: @Petoetje59 No hardware solution on your PC's Ethernet port can magically make your PC route traffic between its Wi-Fi port and its Ethernet port. You're either going to have to set up Internet Connection Sharing (i.e. NAT) in whatever OSes you're running on your PC, or you'll need to replace the PC with a dual Wi-Fi router box (one Wi-Fi port in client mode connected to the external antenna, one Wi-Fi port in AP mode servicing all your client devices inside your caravan). Then you can make your PC be a Wi-Fi client of that dual Wi-Fi router just like everything else inside your caravan.

Comment: Just found such a dual WiFi router combi : Alfa AWUS051NH v2 (the grid antenna is outside the Faraday cage) + Alfa R36 (inside the cage). Are there any other that combine both into a single box - but doesn't break the bank ? Googling for "dual WiFi router" only comes up with "dual-BAND routers".

Comment: The solution you are looking for is a bridge between the wireless adapter and the ethernet adapter. This post may help you [link](http://superuser.com/questions/656998/windows-7-share-internet-connection-with-multiple-network-interfaces)
The best solution here is to connect the antena directly to the router/AP. There are some models able to connect usb antenas, but the most common are devices that uses coaxial antenas (N-Type conector, reverse TNC conector (like most linksys), ...).

Comment: This requires quite a bit of messing with settings - I don't wan't a software but a hardware solution. The laptop has to serve other purposes without having te reset all sorts of obscure settings. I'll go for Spiff's idea.