# Windows Internet connection sharing share to multiples NICs?

Tags: windows, networking, ics

I know windows ICS can share to one NIC, but what if I want to share to more than one NIC? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Do you need multiple NICs because you want to have multiple isolated subnets, or do you need it for other reasons?

Comment: Yes, I need multiple isolated subnets, and they can call access internet.

Comment: Here is similar thread for your reference: [How to use a Windows PC to share multiple network connections?](https://superuser.com/questions/1374913/how-to-use-a-windows-pc-to-share-multiple-network-connections)

Answer (score 0):

Windows bridged network allows you to do that. Open your Network Connections folder (Settings > Network & Internet > Status > Advanced Network Settings > Change adapter options ) , select 2 or more NICs, right click then Bridge.

Comment: I need multiple isolated subnets, and they can call access internet. Bridge is not a solution.

Comment: You might want to update the question to reflect the change in requirements. 
I'm not aware of a solution, aside from bridging those NICs then having physical routers that generate separate networks. Each NIC on the PC can connect to the **WAN** port on each of the routers.